# Expanding system tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, tablespaces

I need to add new data file into the system tablespace because its running out of space. Are there any precautionary measures I should consider since this is a production environment?

Comment: Do you know why the `SYSTEM` tablespace is running out of space?  That's pretty odd in an 11.2 database-- if someone has incorrectly created an object in the `SYSTEM` tablespace, that's something you need to correct.  Even things like `AUD$` are normally moved to `SYSAUX`.  If you really are simply running out of space but everything in the tablespace should be in the tablespace, adding a new data file isn't a big deal.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, its a data warehousing environment, i think tablespace is undersize (just 4GB ) , do you think undersized system tablespace can contribute to the slowness of full database backup(datapump) , second , do i need to take any precautionary measure before adding the new data file into system tablespace , or its just like adding data file for any other tablespace?

Comment: I'm not sure what an "undersized system tablespace" means.  Normally, the `SYSTEM` tablespace doesn't grow meaningfully after the database is installed and the application is created.  A full database backup would be done using RMAN, DataPump would be for creating a logical backup (which is not a substitute for a physical backup-- if you don't have a physical backup, you absolutely need to back up your database).  It seems highly unlikely that performance issues would be caused by a lack of free space in the `SYSTEM` tablespace unless something was badly configured.

Comment: I agree with you , we are working on having the RMAN setup , so can i just resize the system tablespace(increase the size of existing datafile) rather adding the data file on ASM to avoid the overhead on controfile?

Comment: I'm with @JustinCave on this one. Do a root cause analysis first to find out why the tablespace is so big - don't add a datafile or extend yet. If you need help with that, ask another question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're not using `ASM`.

Either set the current datafile to `AUTOEXTEND`:

```
alter database datafile 
   '/full/path/to/system01.dbf' 
autoextend on
next 128m
maxsize 8192m;
```

Or, add a new datafile:

```
alter tablespace SYSTEM
  add datafile '/full/path/to/system02.dbf'
size 512m;
```

Obviously, alter the numbers and path as needed.

Adding a datafile impacts your backups. Take a full backup immediately after adding it - this is the only thing you really have to worry about.

4Gb is *HUGE* for a `SYSTEM` tablespace. I'd first investigate whether there are some large objects being stored in the tablespace that shouldn't be there (`DBA_EXTENTS` is your friend).

Also, note that you cannot remove a datafile once it has been added to the `SYSTEM` tablespace.

Comment: its a data warehousing environment , size of database is 3.5TB, we have LOBs in this db, which is taking most of the space, although we have dedicate tablespace for LOBs.

Comment: @user16308 - The size of the database should have little or nothing to do with the size of the `SYSTEM` tablespace.  The `SYSTEM` tablespace needs a few bytes to store information about the definition of a table or an index.  That space is constant, though, whether the table is empty or whether it has 1 billion rows.